# stub_request chain to_return from array of files

Tags: ruby, rspec2, webmock

i have an array of raw_responses
using web_mock i want use them *as args* of **to_return** method and chain to **stub_request** method:

```rb
#["file1.txt", "subfolder/file_n.txt", "awsome_name.txt"]
rr = Dir.glob(File.expand_path("../../markups/*.txt", __FILE__))
stub_request(:get, "www.google.de").to_return(rr[0]).to_return(rr[1]).to_return(rr[2])
```

How to rewrite last string using enumerator or something like tap to use all array of *rr*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [README](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#multiple-responses-for-repeated-requests), you simply pass the multiple responses to the `to_return` method as arguments. Basically you want something like:

```
stub_request(:get, "www.google.de").to_return(rr[0], rr[1], rr[2])
```

But listing the array values like that is a bit clunky (and won't work with a variable number of responses), so you should instead use Ruby's splat operator:

```
responses = Dir[File.expand_path("../../markups/*.txt", __FILE__)].map{|f| File.read(f)}
stub_request(:get, "www.google.de").to_return(*responses)
```

Answer (score 0):

finaly i did it like this

```
stub = stub_request(:get, "www.google.de")
rr.each { |rf| stub.tap { |s| s.to_return(File.new(rf)) } }
```